# Deep Clone Non Seriazable object in java

Tags: java, object, serialization, clone

I need to deep clone a object which has some non-serialization objects as members in Java. 
Can you provide some reference what can i use for this ?

**Note**: 
Please provide reference to some standard library of java. I don't want to use any unapproved/private package or library.
Or some code pointers how can i clone the object ?

Comment: serializability and cloneable are two different things...

Comment: @f1sh In memory Java Serialization is used as a hack to copy objects.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline that is a very bad hack, what about transient fields?

Comment: @f1sh If you didn't want transient fields in the serialised form, they shouldn't be copied in the "deep clone" either. In practice, I believe/hope, transients are usually used because the serial representation differs from the object representation - e.g. `List`s writing out each element rather than the array, doubly linked list (terrible for Java Serilisation, btw) or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of standardisation of values in Java, I strongly suggest avoiding any dodgy reflection/code generation scheme.

If you can, changing to immutable types removes the need to copy.

Other than that, just write the code neatly. If there are a lot of collections, writing `map` methods will help to avoid the palaver of `Stream`s (and be faster).